# Django - list related instances of class

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have a Projects app with two classes in my models.py (Project, and Deadline). Each Project can have multiple deadlines and my end goal is to list out a Project's deadlines on my web page.

```
class Project(models.model):
    proj_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100, verbose_name = 'Project Name')

class Deadline(models.model):
    deadline_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100, verbose_name = 'Deadline Name')
    proj_name = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm calling the project's deadlines in my html by `{{ deadline.proj_name }}` but it returns nothing. I've read through the documentation and I think I should be doing this through querysets? Can anybody lead me in the right direction? I think I should be calling {{ projects.deadlines }} but I don't know how to structure this to make it happen (sorry still learning)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a `related_name` in your referencing model field (**Deadline.proj_name**), and then you can use a [reverse query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) like `project_instance.deadlines`:

```
class Deadline(models.model):
    deadline_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100, verbose_name = 'Deadline Name')
    proj_name = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='deadelines')
```